# Swift - Parse - pointer column in whereKey condition

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, pfquery

How can I use objectId of pointer column (manufacturerId) in my whereKey condition? The attempts bellow does not work, always return 0 rows.
If I use a column of type String (not pointer) on whereKey, the query returns the correct result (only rows contained in array)

**Attempt ONE**

```
Let array = ["en7fURKoqz", "Y8DAuS2ypK"]
Let query = PFQuery (className: "Posts")
Query.includeKey ("manufacturerId")
Query.whereKey ("manufacturerId", containedIn: array)
```

**Attempt TWO**

```
Let array = ["en7fURKoqz", "Y8DAuS2ypK"]
Let query = PFQuery (className: "Posts")
Query.includeKey ("manufacturerId")
Query.whereKey ("manufacturerId.objectId", containedIn: array)
```

**This Works fine**

```
Let array = ["en7fURKoqz", "Y8DAuS2ypK"]
Let query = PFQuery (className: "Posts")
Query.whereKey ("manufacturerIdString", containedIn: array)
```